# django-rest-framwork UpdateView, DeleteView occurs csrf token error?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

---

I'm using `django-rest-framework` and implement very simple `post` CRUD API.

But the problem is `UpdateView` and `DeleteView` occurs `csrf` error

```
"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

Strange thing is `CreateView` doens't require `csrf` and works very well.

Here is my `view` and `serializer`

`views.py`

```
class PostEditAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    http://example.com/posts/1/edit
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostUpdateSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
```

`serializer.py`

```
class PostUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
        ]
```

I think this is enough for source code.

[image]

After clicked PUT button,

[image]

How can I deal with `csrf` in API?

- I didn't touch any SETTINGS about `Rest-framework`

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions I like to use is to forcefully remove any and all kinds of CSRF checks by instructing Django to do so in the middlewares level.

To do this, create a new middleware class which contains the code to disable CSRF checks, and add the middle ware to your existing list of middlewares to run. Make sure you add your custom middleware AFTER the default authentication middleware being used by Django (Order of middlewares in settings matters).

```
class CSRFDisablerMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

**Beware** I safely use this method since my app is protected using other means of authentication. I am not sure about how you would go about solving this problem if your project needs CSRF authentication in certain areas and not in others. The method described above will disable CSRF authentication throughout your entire Django project.